# How to extract chart from Excel to Email using ClosedXML in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, mailkit, closedxml

I wanted to extract a chart from my Excel file and put it into my Email body. I am using ClosedXML to handle my Excel file like inserting something into Excel file or extract something from it.

What I've tried:

```
Dim pic = worksheetAvr.Picture("Chart2")
Dim image As Image
image = Image.FromStream(pic.ImageStream)
builder.HtmlBody += "<img src = '" & image & "'>"
```

It shows

> Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'Image'.

in the `builder.HtmlBody` line.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to concatenate some string with an actual image, instead of the name of the image so the `&` operator won't work.

Comment: Yes, true. I fixed it by saving the chart as an image and get the contentID. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to use Comma seperated files.

then simply Split the string on each line.

```
split(FileContent, ",")
```

Excell can also open these files. the format is .csv

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. However, I fixed it by saving the chart as an image and get the content ID instead. Thanks a lot.